# Cooling an MCU to boost performance

Tags: microcontroller, cooling

As part of an ongoing project of computers ran by microcontrollers, one of my desktop models will overclock it's main MCU far past recommended operating frequency, since the first model isn't very fast. I'm thinking about using a Cortex M0 overclocked to about 100MHz, compared to the recommended 50MHz. I know that traditional CPUs perform faster at cooler temperatures, so would cooling the M0 to sub-zero temperatures using a thermoelectric module allow me to overclock it to what I want? Also, I would like to hear what you think about stability at these speeds.

Comment: "I know that traditional CPUs perform faster at cooler temperatures ..." Not strictly true. The additional cooling prevents them from burning themselves up when the clock frequency is increased.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Wait, would that mean my M0 would burn up too if I were to overclock it?

Comment: Without sufficient cooling, yes. But the definition of "sufficient" varies.

Comment: To clarify what @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams is saying - You can run traditional desktop CPUs at a ridiculous overclock with no cooling without issue. It won't run for very *long*, but it'll still run. The spectactular cooling is to allow the removal of heat more effectively, not because the silicon needs to be that cool to overclock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This blog describes an [experimental STM32F103 overclock](http://blog.tkjelectronics.dk/2010/02/stm32-overclocking/) of a 72MHz STM32F103 (Cortex-M3) to 128MHz.

It includes the C source code to reconfigure the clock.

One of the blog's comments *claims* a [72MHz STM32F107](http://blog.tkjelectronics.dk/2010/02/stm32-overclocking/#comment-5770) was accidentally overclocked to 225MHz, and worked with PWM, ADC and UART.

Another comment *claims* a [24MHz STM32F100](http://blog.tkjelectronics.dk/2010/02/stm32-overclocking/#comment-11804) was successfully overclocked to 64MHz 2.67x overclock.

Then this forum post describes reproducing those results experimental results on an [overclocked Maple STM32F103](http://forums.leaflabs.com/topic.php?id=31#post-114), again 72MHz overclocked to 128MHz.

That 128MHz is due to the limited main crystal PLL multiplier, which is a maximum of 16. Hence an 8MHz crystal could only be multiplied upto 128MHz. An STM32F103 can operate with a 16MHz crystal, so theoretically it would allow a 16 multiplier to be applied to 16MHz, allowing a 256MHz ceiling to be explored.

One important points is some peripherals and buses might not be able to keep up.

One authors warn there might not be enough flexibility to configure buses and peripherals clock dividers to work with an overclocked system clock. To be fair, neither author pursued this enough to bottom out all the details. IMHO many peripherals seem to have enough flexibility to work on an STM32, though USB is a problem on some of the older parts.

NB: these were stock parts, with no additional cooling, or higher supply voltages.

As well as ST's Cortex-M0, it might also be worth exploring the 72MHz STM32F3. It has the same Cortex-M4 CPU (hardware FPU, DSP extensions) as the STM32F4, which are specified to run upto 180MHz. Maybe an STM32F3 might use the same CPU design and geometry?

You might have to search the web to track down the most 'overclockable' MCU's, but [STM32F](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1169) appears to work.

Edit:
You could get an [STM32 Nucleo](http://www2.mouser.com/Search/Refine.aspx?Keyword=nucleo) (about $11) which is also an mbed. mbed is a cloud-hosted IDE and C++ compiler, so you wouldn't need to install anything to try this. It might take an afternoon, and you would have the core of an answer.

Answer (score 6):

There is a very significant difference in how MCUs are designed and how desktop CPUs are designed.  Desktop CPUs are what is known as 'thermal limited' - their performance is limited by how much heat is produced.  If you keep the die temperature constant while cranking up the voltage and clock frequency, it is possible to get significantly more performance out of the chip as there is still some timing margin available.

However, low power MCUs are a different beast.  They are generally designed for low power operation.  The circuits inside are built with larger transistors and wires, and they are tuned to operate up to the design frequency while consuming as little power as possible by trading timing margin for power consumption.  Because of this, there is very little advantage to active cooling for an MCU.  It may be possible to get a small increase if you crank up the voltage, but I doubt you will be able to get anywhere near a 2x overclock without major stability issues.

Comment: Alright, so sub-zero temperatures is going a little overboard then.